# What is best approach to implement a popular product sorting in any e-commerce?

Tags: sorting, search, e-commerce

I'm working on an e-commerce application and need to implement a "sort by" panel, like Popularity, Price Low to High, Price High to Low, Discount and New Arrivals.

But I'm confused with the "sort by popularity" option. What should be the best approach for finding any popular items?

There are some cases which are given below:

Sort popular items on the basis of

- Their average rating (Rating High to Low)
- Their seller's average rating (Rating High to Low)
- Their view count (Most view to Low)
- Their sells count (Most sell to Low)

What other scenarios are there to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Sale count** is called best selling.

The **seller's rating** is not a measure of product so its misleading.

**View count** and **Product rating** could be used together to sort by popularity.